# Print the Black Mirror episode title

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

Given two integers, *s* and *e*, print the title of *[Black Mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Mirror)* series #*s* episode #*e*.

Expected output is as below, case sensitive. Output for blank cells and invalid inputs is unspecified.

```
e↓s→                          1                  2                     3               4                              5                6
 1 | The National Anthem       | Be Right Back    | Nosedive            | USS Callister | Striking Vipers              | Joan Is Awful  |
 2 | Fifteen Million Merits    | White Bear       | Playtest            | Arkangel      | Smithereens                  | Loch Henry     |
 3 | The Entire History of You | The Waldo Moment | Shut Up and Dance   | Crocodile     | Rachel, Jack, and Ashley Too | Beyond the Sea |
 4 |                           |                  | San Junipero        | Hang the DJ   |                              | Mazey Day      |
 5 |                           |                  | Men Against Fire    | Metalhead     |                              | Demon 79       |
 6 |                           |                  | Hated in the Nation | Black Museum  |                              |                |
```

(The episode "White Christmas" is grouped with series 2 on Netflix, but originally aired as a standalone special, so it is not part of the challenge. The film *Bandersnatch* is likewise standalone and exempt.)

This question was posted before the release of series 6, at a time when it appeared the future of *Black Mirror* was in jeopardy. I have added series 6 to the challenge; answers posted before this edit are still considered valid.

Comment: Can we make a function that returns the title instead of printing it?

Comment: @Dion As far as I know, returning rather than printing is always allowable.

Comment: @Dion Returning is just printing to the function output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 162 bytes

```
!x'x!¶¨Σṅ←ÿ‼⌋xżFE«Ȯ⌊Żψ'xΣẏ>ï?₀fẏu₈eṙ‼ḂkxẇïBȦrxΣ«QẆḟṁŸ)⁶ıex₉?²tx«‼UÜUÄd□Δ'xS▲⌋ȷ9oxṀËäαγFxHȦ∂↕εṄ|≠USSχ⁷ıżxŻKȦ£Ġx£%Øx□´'ËDJxẎȦlḊh₈Ċż_ṀÿKi▼V₉→xSmi►&η$x£ƒ´,⌋ȷ@,Ädÿ¿◄θ⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7NSsNQEIWfpaAGoStdubEiWsSuJNStGyuVKoJamIWLJMT0F5WiVUFopRKEgrW1tkkaCNybSFa3z3DnReLobg5858xXLF@UkiQFCqTYhL2LnnSv0brjAWo@NhsQ@dlt1o8/sFmPZvOqAkR4t@t8kEFDO6KzjEa1IN1n4qVjlEB6FT7YjO1zIll/T3qWdDrS1SNnGfVJOCwAGrUMG10C61Mnz1/y3DzE9qu4V0DF9oi@xtO1M5Cuxhv8TQzFVxZ2YhurBloP4lu65hXWunlVnVdQn4bDyIdolott1gu7wHqL/Alojo0V3tjaJZ@b2D6RTr1IomE98g/@hoPcMbb9fVJBqwXqKSVvSUwXqP/TYuP0v8RGmsx4wAJ8NIWD@meSJCvJ6i8)

A perfect task for Husk's string compression. Seasons are separated with newlines and episodes are separated with 'x'.
Then:

```
!x'x!¶¨...
      ¨...     Big compressed string
     ¶         Split on newlines
    !          Take the line corresponding to given season
 x'x           Split on 'x'
!              Take the title of the given episode
```

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 213 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.•Ω?"Λ1äγÍθ}Æuмï∍βb6G¨—Wc“jép¡úórÑ9ǝ‘øδs@!иésb•#`”0á½Ú©ÿ0ŽÚÿ0Çˆ,—É, ÿÍ±…«00
0€€ƒ³à¬ÿ0ßà‡ÈÝìs0€€îÆ„ª of€î00
0€ïƒ©‚ƒ0„¸Ÿâ0€€Ò´doœÂ00
«¢d in ÿï¹0ÄÃÿ0†•ÿ0À…€¾ ÿ–›0†ŽŠ€ÿ0…±†¤ŠÄ
ƒÏ—´0USS„Òÿ0Aÿ0Cÿ0ÂŒ ÿ DJ0îÊÿ”¶¡0δ¡IèIèðÚ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##NU9NSwJBGL77K7a6SkwgQaeKgqirRNcyC@yQ0dIxGEzsAyRaO4Rm7S4ibkpWLrFJJrwPa4dg8TfMH9neCYN3mHd4Pidv7mRye3E8q6QbeYvTUW0OjaiHchSconQy/kRXXZSjt8z8GrWUvN3aVfL@AN4ROeijd4ybhe@6kncIIt9cmhoH8MwMe81sK1kXcGiAKnkYipAXvnD@U0qyDy6TBoYo06uSTWoLkRCq0OEZWdSDTR3NfYStpIML1NExJzieUVLygZ6M/P7fcyJFl5WektWRJTQehAHcf41FfjYfVlBgMrXJzRq5Qx3fpQ@BIs44TEnOcnWq5EYsoi9mKFlRsq/BcBDa2kozm7q1TY3QRjExsnDNHyJfbKbTnAyLOct8VrRZIbTYxljdEFz8ShvW6Z0cEfnkrKPFgxfU4jiVSP0C) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##NVBLSwJRFN73KybbStwWCa0sKoIWbiJqmaaBLZpoaBlcLOwBEo0tQrNmRMRJycohpugB52NsEQz@hvtHpnOj4F7uOXyvc49pZXPFQjy9mFlNLWbWE1Yha5k7Bj6TRmG3aJn5AteGKttGIh1PKtmMvHQiqk@hFQ1QiYIDlPdHb@irk0r0lEstUUfJy7VNJa@34e2Si1cM9nAx89VQ8gpB5Fuz46MAnpVjr4kNJRsCLr2jRh4@RcgFPzj@LifZB6dJTkeFHpVsU1eIMaFKPT5DmwZwqKe5t3CUdHGCBnrWH457lJW8oTvD3Ppt/6Tos9JTsja0hcaDMEDzX2OTnzfDKkpMpi4180ZRLwJ9ehE4wiGHKclZTZ0qeSIW0QczlKwq@arB8D10tJVmtvXUDrVCB0djQxvn/CHyxerKCifDZs4c33ltVgptveWFZcGDn2nDBj2TKyKf3HV0MujgAfU4eUDP6fgH).

**Explanation:**

```python
.•Ω?"Λ1äγÍθ}Æuмï∍βb6G¨—Wc“jép¡úórÑ9ǝ‘øδs@!иésb•
            "# Push compressed string "head the rocodile rkangel ister ipero and test dive the hem and ereens ers"
 #           # Split it on spaces
  `          # Pop and push each string separated to the stack
”0á½Ú©ÿ0ŽÚÿ0Çˆ,—É, ÿÍ±…«00
0€€ƒ³à¬ÿ0ßà‡ÈÝìs0€€îÆ„ª of€î00
0€ïƒ©‚ƒ0„¸Ÿâ0€€Ò´doœÂ00
«¢d in ÿï¹0ÄÃÿ0†•ÿ0À…€¾ ÿ–›0†ŽŠ€ÿ0…±†¤ŠÄ
ƒÏ—´0USS„Òÿ0Aÿ0Cÿ0ÂŒ ÿ DJ0îÊÿ”
             # Push dictionary string "0 Striking Vipÿ0 Smithÿ0 Rachel, Jack, ÿ Ashley Too00\n
             # 0 The National Antÿ0 Fifteen Million Merits0 The Entire History of You00\n
             # 0 Be Right Back0 White Bear0 The Waldo Moment00\n
             #  Hated in ÿ Nation0 Noseÿ0 Playÿ0 Shut Up ÿ Dance0 San Junÿ0 Men Against Fire\n
             #  Black Museum0USS Callÿ0Aÿ0Cÿ0 Hang ÿ DJ0 Metalÿ",
             # with all `ÿ` automatically filled with the strings on the stack
 ¶¡          # Split it on newlines
   0δ¡       # Split each line on 0s
             #  [[""," Striking Vipers"," Smithereens"," Rachel, Jack, and Ashley Too","",""],
             #   [""," The National Anthem"," Fifteen Million Merits"," The Entire History of You","",""],
             #   [""," Be Right Back"," White Bear"," The Waldo Moment","",""],
             #   [" Hated in the Nation"," Nosedive"," Playtest"," Shut Up and Dance"," San Junipero"," Men Against Fire"],
             #   [" Black Museum","USS Callister","Arkangel","Crocodile"," Hang the DJ"," Metalhead"]]
      Iè     # Index the first input-integer into it (0-based and with wraparound)
        Iè   # Index the second input-integer into that list (0-based and with wraparound)
          ðÛ # Remove any leading spaces
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (sections *How to use the dictionary?* and *How to compress strings not part of the dictionary?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand how the used compressed and dictionary strings work.

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 202 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü○b(╠◘qÅñÿ[%Uδö╬ε#êc∙╪≈ü╒┘ú┴tÆ↔nU¥┴♣ßª•┼<\╣`vΘ╒°²~♦∙'E♂○N½←àp▄û'XpéIê┼z♂Qìa~Æq7-T⌐ ○¡B▬#√╤cçµM╖Æ♦N╜Ü◄4òτ`≈úG{╧►)┴╬║º,Φ┤╫ÿα►]Q╬≈♠ [εjy0z▲dΘÜ╚é6♥#ö»ë'KC▬.W◙)lH↓√↓ö¿▐▌φ┬;┼ΣuΓuΣiè‼x╘ö╝▐┴ßIG•∙¿╦↓AQt}yd◘$éⁿ≤←
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81096228cc08718fa4985b2555eb94ceee238863f9d8f781d5d9a3c174921d6e559dc105e1a607c53c5cb96076e9d5f8fd7e04f927450b094eab1b8570dc96275870824988c57a0b518d617e9271372d54a92009ad421623fbd16387e64db792044ebd9a113495e760f7a3477bcf1029c1cebaa72ce8b4d798e0105d51cef706205bee6a79307a1e64e99ac88236032394af89274b43162e570a296c4819fb1994a8deddedc23bc5e475e275e4698a1378d494bcdec1e1494707f9a8cb194151747d7964082482fcf31b&i=1+1%0A1+2%0A5+1%0A3+6&a=1&m=2)

This program takes episode and season as input, separated by a space.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 192 bytes

```
`λƛ ¬ε Ṫṅ¥ṗXṠ↳ ÷⁋ Ṗ≈sXλƛ ∆ɾ ∧Ġ of λß
Be ¬ẏ λǑX∧… ∞↑Xλƛ W…±o ɽ⁋
₁ḣ¦ḭX∨±∨ḊXż≬ Up λ¬ ↔÷X⟑ɖ ∨Ǐ °↔X←Ġd in λλ ⌐±
USS ⟑«iḊꜝrXArk›ǎXC≥ẋo∩ȧeX⟩ẇ λλ DJX∆↑÷≠X¬⁼ ¢⁋
Ẇ± Ŀʀ□ẊX€∧□Ṅ↳¾X₄ð, ¢…, λ¬ §⋏ ⟑⋏`↵\X/?i?i
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%CE%BB%C6%9B%20%C2%AC%CE%B5%20%E1%B9%AA%E1%B9%85%C2%A5%E1%B9%97X%E1%B9%A0%E2%86%B3%20%C3%B7%E2%81%8B%20%E1%B9%96%E2%89%88sX%CE%BB%C6%9B%20%E2%88%86%C9%BE%20%E2%88%A7%C4%A0%20of%20%CE%BB%C3%9F%0ABe%20%C2%AC%E1%BA%8F%20%CE%BB%C7%91X%E2%88%A7%E2%80%A6%20%E2%88%9E%E2%86%91X%CE%BB%C6%9B%20W%E2%80%A6%C2%B1o%20%C9%BD%E2%81%8B%0A%E2%82%81%E1%B8%A3%C2%A6%E1%B8%ADX%E2%88%A8%C2%B1%E2%88%A8%E1%B8%8AX%C5%BC%E2%89%AC%20Up%20%CE%BB%C2%AC%20%E2%86%94%C3%B7X%E2%9F%91%C9%96%20%E2%88%A8%C7%8F%20%C2%B0%E2%86%94X%E2%86%90%C4%A0d%20in%20%CE%BB%CE%BB%20%E2%8C%90%C2%B1%0AUSS%20%E2%9F%91%C2%ABi%E1%B8%8A%EA%9C%9DrXArk%E2%80%BA%C7%8EXC%E2%89%A5%E1%BA%8Bo%E2%88%A9%C8%A7eX%E2%9F%A9%E1%BA%87%20%CE%BB%CE%BB%20DJX%E2%88%86%E2%86%91%C3%B7%E2%89%A0X%C2%AC%E2%81%BC%20%C2%A2%E2%81%8B%0A%E1%BA%86%C2%B1%20%C4%BF%CA%80%E2%96%A1%E1%BA%8AX%E2%82%AC%E2%88%A7%E2%96%A1%E1%B9%84%E2%86%B3%C2%BEX%E2%82%84%C3%B0%2C%20%C2%A2%E2%80%A6%2C%20%CE%BB%C2%AC%20%C2%A7%E2%8B%8F%20%E2%9F%91%E2%8B%8F%60%E2%86%B5%5CX%2F%3Fi%3Fi&inputs=3%0A1&header=&footer=)

```
`...`         # Dictionary-compressed string 
     ↵        # Split on newlines
      \X/     # Split on Xs (vectorised)
         ?i?i # Index input twice
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 224 bytes

```
§⪪§⪪”}∨⊙α⁷ξ{⪪\`Ｇ↔Iλ?Ｉ⟧∧≕EαγＲ≔³E↙\`UκêΣJ4⧴Ｕ↙�～Ｂ⁺^dF]η8A⊖ξ≡Ｗ¦¶⧴hNνＸ^#Ol▶⊙｜Ｑ|,/(:ZＮQξζG↥≧⟲ψ∨]⮌⊖≦#Rς+vQlＫ≧⦄⁴φＣ7“L¡⊘[⁸⮌!⌕↗Ｏp;⧴‹Hr,◧⁹‖·›↨χ➙⌕↙bＭ″G@ⅉ<↔ＧnQＳ§‖⎚Þ⟧⊗¤E*ⅈ⁶℅Orν%Ｆ¤×Xbη＆◨χＪＷCＸz�Π8D>νＢ⁶≔Ｘ″~↖≡@/ÀＹ#¦▷Ｉ¿↷Φ№!｜↔δＭKＵλÀE§χＵo:γ@▷”¶Ｎ⸿Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY9BawJBDIX/StiTgr20x55WraiwIq5WCnNJd6MTHDOSyUr99dtRSg/tMe/xXr7XeNQmYuj7tbLYoLSFtPQ1qC@B/17FBhtPYQRLbE4jQGmhTD7QDbYxOq1N@cRyhHe@kKYsnNk8KZEkJ1tP8CbGSjDnZFFvEA/wETund2uFxlEwQCk5c3Y644PlJFQcQnagImX76dljaCNU8UxiTscEGz56g3HGcrr3bARjQnUyR6MWWMB@XzhdxUQtX8npOuDNKOWO2ncGu8tj0xSlyWaNAstO7lvyuCqjlEdkSQazPMLJOOR3UHWJuoy7q2uYYEZNRuq01BPKkYLTicYmthxy4zxLD5Lp8l5oGDxhW4ygcFIMR7CQS2er7vxJOhgO77L@l4evff8Cz/3TNXwD) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
    ”...”       Compressed table of episode titles
   ⪪     ¶      Split on `\n`s
  §       Ｎ     Cyclically index by series
 ⪪         ⸿    Split on `\r`s
§           Ｎ   Cyclically index by episode
                Implicitly print
```

Because Charcoal uses cyclic 0-indexing the last series and last episode of each series will wrap around to 0 so they actually appear first in the table.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 353 bytes

```javascript
s=>e=>`The National Anthem|Fifteen Million Merits|The Entire History of You||||Be Right Back|White Bear|The Waldo Moment||||Nosedive|Playtest|Shut Up and Dance|San Junipero|Men Against Fire|Hated in the Nation|USS Callister|Arkangel|Crocodile|Hang the DJ|Metalhead|Black Museum|Striking Vipers|Smithereens|Rachel, Jack, and Ashley Too`.split`|`[s*6+e-7]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZBNSwMxEIbv/oo5@g22W/VSofUDKayIWxURocPudHdsmpRktlCY/17Til6agw45vXnnyUM@cYmh9LyQk@Xletpfh/4V9a8m44bgAYWdRQMDKw3N9Y6nQmQhZ2PiBeTkWYJuqrdW2BPccxDnV@Cm8OZajTMkeOK6ERhiOdPXhoVgSOi3W69oKge5m5OVTfnBBap4SfpocCUURIumFXheANoKbtCWpAVaGLWWF@Sd5tFmUCPbIHAXBfQehSpgC/Lrr89FAdcYlYOQ14Gfoa3J6LV3pavYbJZsvV24GUWioGkIKx2aaAx5G6idayGeZxxrL5uHgxZzjgs@/kbQJywbMscwiv3jrekgNIZWMHZuchoWhmWik/dweH5EJxcf69LZ4AydGlfvw3T/7CAeONjbjTvpuLsT/8xOu5Nmd9Lszr/Y3TS7m2Z3U@xtnKXjXjo@/7tglhbM0oJZWjBLC2Zpwexfgr20YC8t2PsWXH8B)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 360 bytes

```python
lambda s,e:"The National Anthem|Fifteen Million Merits|The Entire History of You||||Be Right Back|White Bear|The Waldo Moment||||Nosedive|Playtest|Shut Up and Dance|San Junipero|Men Against Fire|Hated in the Nation|USS Callister|Arkangel|Crocodile|Hang the DJ|Metalhead|Black Museum|Striking Vipers|Smithereens|Rachel, Jack, and Ashley Too".split("|")[s*6+e-7]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PZBNS8NAEED/ypBTq1UogoLgoR@WUkiRprWIehibSXboZjfsToTA/Pe66cG57ns7j2l7Md49XKqXr4vF5qdEiBN6zvaGYIvC3qGFmRNDja64EiIHOVubHiCnwBJ1QF@dcCBYcxQfevAVfPhO08wJdlwbgTmezno0LARzwnC1jmhLD7lvyMkAb32kkn9J3yz2QlG0MJ3AoQV0JSzRnUgLdLDpHLcUvOapZlYjuyiwSgG6RqES2IH89@uhKGCBKTkKBZ2FM7qarC6CP/mS7SC5@iosN@lHQWsIS53bVAx5F6lrtJDAZ07Y@7A4atFwEkK6RtQdngzZCWwSP7mWzqKx1MPe@@w@tpZllGk2/ow3j7d09/R9aQM7GVWj6WQ6Hl/@AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 291 + 45 bytes

<sup>up to series 6</sup>

```bash
base64 -w0|cut -d2 -f$2|cut -d3 -f$1|tr 45 \ ,
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LVHLTtxAEFSu_gofcmSjxN0L4ehlgzarGEWYhxDJoWO3d0Y7nkEz7SAjvoBfyIUD8E_ka-jd5dSq7qruqpl_T38omcfH50G6ydfXT4p4H_PJ7ef7ZpB80hb5pPtYvAPYgC_3EnOc5r_yvZ3qXfxyDXv5_u__Hx7ODOMJiQ2eHJZeDPcwYzy1KyM4o2YNJyFxa_8ynNc1HpFzNglHqCXatfUrvLA3HBMsA2Uevycsb7vBFce2E2aPlVVB0MrRSoJLY4VxxhThp6NROAmUcU1-xQ7q3ur9qLIEP7LQGFywj2Ox8fjNi42MCz0e4oihw6swwGZySa4NWIWevUBtBsHzGyTf4px8w3AUQxOy1jqGU2oMuykuNdZ0SymTcTziWQgaegzaUQNYMxUANXlcDn6TLsBCHW5n8yVkUNGdquY0Kq3SkOWKrE-Cx2pRG0LOMLUAc-41-sGh0hYk3KL12yW7B4eZoyZbYzUkHvrsZfefbw)

The input is generated with
`cat table | tail -n 6 | sed "s/ *| */|/g" | cut -d "|" -f 2-7 | tr "\n| ," "2345" | sed "s/332$//" | base64 -d`.